# SpringBoot stores configs in BOOT

Tags: java, spring-boot, packaging

I have a spring boot application as myapp and I have some configs that I need to be externalized. They are originally located in a distribution project under `main/resource/config`

When I run the maven build, the the tar.gz has the config folder as well as the myapp.jar.
This myapp.jar has a BOOT folder which also has all the files from the config folder outside the jar as well. Now when I change the config folder out side. Springboot still reads the config files from inside the BOOT folder inside the jar. How to read external config files.

Answer (score 0):

Because your external config files are not in classpath, so springboot wouldn't know these files, it will search files from classpath.

Here is doc of [externalized config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). If you use external configs, you need to set `spring.config.location` when you run springboot, like

`java -Dspring.config.location=file:/gfs/config/post/post.properties,/gfs/config/post/post_pwd.properties,./config/db-config.properties,./config/db-passwd.properties  -jar myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: is there a way to not add them into the BOOT without adding Dspring.config.location=() in the command

Comment: @sarmahdi, or you need to read file by your self in your code. It's more work than setting `spring.config.location`

Answer (score 0):

sarmahdi - you can try this...

java -Dconfig_base_dir=/opt/tomcat/conf/bpm -jar myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

```
@Configuration
    @PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("file:${config_base_dir}/app.properties"),
        @PropertySource("file:${config_base_dir}/dbconfig.properties")
 })
public class PostConfig {
```

For more samples...
[Mkyong java](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just used file:config/myconfig.properties in the application.yaml so instead of looking inside the jar it looked for the folder config and then in there. If i used classpath:/config/myconfig.properties then it will take whats bundled inside the jar